# Alternative Button Combo for Alt + Tab in VMWare Horizon Client?

Tags: windows-10, vmware, alt-tab

I'm working remotely via a VMWare Horizon Client portal to access my Windows 10 desktop. I have zero admin rights to modify registries, install software, access the client's settings, etc. Is there another button combo that replicates the Alt+Tab function? It's driving me crazy popping back to my computer's active windows and not the windows within the client.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Horizon User Guide](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-HTML-Access/2006/html-access-user.pdf?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIMoHcCWAXAxgCyQOwOYAJlsATAewQGdDUN9IUBaFMAIxAF8g):

Enable the Windows key for remote desktops:

> To enable this key, click the Open Settings Window toolbar button in the sidebar and turn on Enable Windows Key for Desktops

The actual instructions may vary depending on the client, but the setting should be there.

> Important After you turn on Enable Windows Key for Desktops, you must press Ctrl+Win (on Windows), Ctrl+Command (on Mac), or Ctrl+Search (on Chromebook) to simulate pressing the Windows key

You should be able to use Windows + Tab to switch between programs after enabling the setting.

I am unable to test this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pin functions to the taskbar and then win+digit. So you can pin many directories in this way and go exact one without sorting like ctrl+tab or win+tab.

for example win+8 -> open Chrome window or D disc

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/pin-apps-and-folders-to-the-desktop-or-taskbar-f3c749fb-e298-4cf1-adda-7fd635df6bb0#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

Answer (score 0):

If you can run basic `exe` files inside the instance (that don't require any installation), then you could download [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on your own computer, create an `ahk` script with the following line:

```
LCtrl & CapsLock::AltTabMenu
```

Save the file, then compile it to `exe` using `Convert .ahk to .exe` (you can find it in your Start Menu after installing AutoHotkey).

Now, assuming you can copy the compiled executable to your instance and run it, you can invoke the Alt-Tab Menu using <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

Note that you can use a different key combination is this one does not work for you. [Here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) you can find the list of all keys.